# Rails 4 - how to track users' activity and don't overload the app + MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I want to implement a tracking system for monitoring users' activity within the application.
The application is currently used within the business hours by about 600-2000 users.

I originally wanted to use a `before_filter` to the `ApplicationController` where every time a user would click a link, I'd save information such as user/admin id, `params[:controller]`, `params[:action]` and other params of actions to the database. (I know about gems like `audited` - but not sure if I use them).

However I am wondering if I basically don't kill the app when for every click within the system will be called database to insert some data into it.

I was thinking of using a background method ([sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)) for logging the action into the database.

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question.  ApplicationController + before_filter + sidekiq job is a very common way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :log_request

  def log_request
    RequestLogger.perform_async(params[:controller], params[:action], current_user.id)
  end
end

class RequestLogger
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(controller, action, user_id)
    # Save data to the database
  end
end
```

More or less.

Comment: Thanks, John, I had something similar on my mind, just wasn't sure if it's the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'd urge you to use a logfile.  Compresses easily and then you can process entire logfiles in a batch.  Just update Rails to log the session ID and you can track individual sessions.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, for your answer. I am trying to google this approach, but so far don't have anything specific. Do you mean to use the `before_filter` + Sidekiq and save the data to a eg. CSV file? Wouldn't be loading the file to get users activity (for a specific day or whole history) too slow due to loading/filtering data from a file? Or do I miss anything else? Thank you.